# NASDAQ TotalView ITCH order reference number number characteristics

Tags: data, equities, algorithmic-trading, programming

I am building a custom hash implementation for storing NASDAQ ITCH order messages. Obviously this is keyed on the order reference number and I am wondering if these numbers are sequential, random or exhibit any interesting characteristics in their distribution.

The hash table will be on a relatively low memory device and knowing these characteristics will allow me to efficiently optimise the datastructure.

Comment: This question is very similar to your [previous one](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3031/limit-order-book-size).

Comment: The only thing you're guaranteed is that they are day unique. Anything else would be heuristic, which I'd urge you to try to measure yourself if you think it is important.

Comment: @chrisaycock Similar although the previous one was volume, this one refers to the order IDs. I have added "reference" to the question to try and make this more clear.

Comment: @LouisMarascio I may have to although this probably wont be possible as its a purely academic project.

Comment: No offense, but I'll never buy that optimizing the hash map on NASDAQ's order id's is a purely academic project.

Comment: I'm a MEng student at Imperial College London. My final year project brief was just a title "Algorithmic Trading and Low Latency Computation". Purely academic.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does IC provide access to direct NASDAQ feeds to the students?

Comment: No. I am generating data and using samples provided on their website but I would like it to be as realistic as possible. I thought it would just be a case of someone linking to a specification on their site but its probably easier to just profile the samples.

Comment: @JonathanEvans Send me a note via email. I might be able to provide some help. It is my last name at gmail.

Comment: Hi Louis. Thanks. I have just emailed you

Comment: Hi, I know this thread is old, but I would like to know this answer is well.  I too am working on school project, putting order book on an FPGA.  My teammates and I are interested in learning the statistics of the order reference number for hashing purposes as well.  If anyone has an answer, I would be very interested.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't work with ITCH, but I would do the following:

1) ask the data provider.

2) whenever a new order arrives, record it's ID separately, and then analyze for a pattern.

Most probably they are sequentially growing numbers per instrument.